# External component throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, caliburn.micro

I have a question. I have Access Database and WPF application. The application is Build in 32-bit, and Access Database is 32-bit. And every once in a while the applications show me an error when connecting to database.. External component trows an exception. And eavn if I eat the error or try to connect to database again it doesn't work. I have to restart the application and then it works again until it throws and error again in next 15 or so database connection transaction. If you know what I mean.

How can I restart that error so I can again connect to database or eavn prevent the error from throwing.

Please help me.
I don't know what kind of code to provide that is relevant.

```
        try
        {
            List<IDModel> output = new List<IDModel>();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Conn))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE [STATUS] = @status;", connection))
                {

                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", _status);

                    var reader = await Command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        output.Add(InsertID
                                            ((int)reader["ID"], (string)reader["STANDARD"], (string)reader["NAZIV"], (string)reader["POSLOVNA ENOTA"],
                                            (string)reader["IZVOR NESKLADNOSTI"], (string)reader["ODDELEK"], (string)reader["OPIS"],

                                            (string)reader["SLIKA 1"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["SLIKA 2"].ToString(), (string)reader["SLIKA 3"].ToString(), (string)reader["SLIKA 4"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["SLIKA 5"].ToString(), (string)reader["EXCEL 1"].ToString(), (string)reader["PDF 1"].ToString(),

                                            (string)reader["SLIKA 6"].ToString(), (string)reader["EXCEL 2"].ToString(), (string)reader["PDF 2"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["KOREKCIJA"].ToString(),

                                            (string)reader["SLIKA 7"].ToString(), (string)reader["EXCEL 3"].ToString(), (string)reader["PDF 3"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["KOREKTIVNI"].ToString(), (string)reader["VZROK"].ToString(),

                                            (string)reader["OCENA"].ToString(), (string)reader["OPOMBA"].ToString(),

                                            (string)reader["NESKLADNOST ODPRL"].ToString(), (string)reader["KOREKCIJA PODAL"].ToString(), (string)reader["NESKLADNOST ZAPRL"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["NESKLADNOST VALIDIRAL"].ToString(), (string)reader["ROK ZA REŠITEV"].ToString(),

                                            (bool)reader["BIG EVENT"],

                                            (string)reader["NESKLADNOST ODPRTA"].ToString(), (string)reader["KOREKCIJA PODANA"].ToString(),
                                            (string)reader["NESKLADNOST ZAPRTA"].ToString(), (string)reader["NESKLADNOST VALIDIRANA"].ToString()
                                            ));
                    }
                }

                return output;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
            
        }
```

Best regards!

Comment: Is it possible that connection calls interupt each other?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading the back end from Access to a more robust rdbms such as SQL Express or MySQL ?

Comment: When you start the app up. Does it perhaps compact and repair the database?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: I did consider, but departments are different so it would take ages to convert to SQL. Thats why I am looking for quick fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the problem is with the access database. In my experience, Access simply fail sometime, without apparent reason. I have spent quite a bit of time investigating access crashes without reaching a solution. There are some things that might help:

1. Ensure you are only ever using the database from a single thread.
2. Ensure all database related objects are correctly disposed.
3. Ensure the databases are not to large, there is a 2Gb limit on database size. Running compaction might help.
4. Add better error handling, catch errors and retry the operation. If repeated failures occur, dispose and recreate the database connection.
5. Move the database access to another process. This can help with error handling, allowing you to restart the entire process if needed.

My preferred solution is to avoid using access at all. Spend the time to port the data to some real database instead.

Comment: And how do you mean to dispose and recreate the database. I don't understand that line? I mean yes it would be much better to move to sql, and probably I will need to do that. But the app is in production and the bug was not saw before. So you mean that every Access data call should not be paralel, they should allways be one by one?

Comment: @zigimun assuming you are using ado.net, you should have a sql connection that you should be able to dispose and re-create.

Comment: @zigimun, yes, in my experience access works better if it does not have to manage concurrent requests. Your experience might be different.

Comment: I updated my question. So where should I dispose the connection?

Comment: @zigimun, you already do, if an exception occurs, the using statement ensures the connection is disposed. Note that I said *might* help, I never managed to solve my problem after all. If the problem is new, then you can try to find the change that introduced the problem.

Comment: The problem is old we just didnt notice it.  I mean what bothers me is that I cannot refresh the connection to Access. That I must restart the app.

Comment: @zigimun , it should be possible in a well written library to restart the connection, but I'm not so certain that access is well written. So you might need to either live with the problem, find a workaround, or switch to something better.

Comment: Mybe I should realy switch to SQL